# Qual è il significato di "raspa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> Il pidugello attaccava anche cani e gatti e li riempiva di rogna, era tutto un grattarsi e un mulinare di peli. E se riusciva a entrare nei pantaloni o sotto le sottane, erano eczemi e **raspe** da non camminare un mese.

Il "pidugello" è un insetto inventato da Benni per questo romanzo, ma quello che non capisco è il significato di "raspa" in questo testo. L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che sembri avere senso in questo contesto. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A me sembra più semplicemente relativo al verbo [raspare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/raspare/), che indica anche:

> **b. fig.** Di tessuti ruvidi, di cibi e bevande troppo forti e acri, produrre su una parte del corpo una sgradevole sensazione di raschiamento, di irritazione: *una maglia di lana grossolana che raspa la pelle*

La "raspa", quindi, evocherebbe sia la superficie della pelle resa ruvida dalla rogna, sia il senso di prurito sulla pelle.

Benni è solito estendere a piacere il significato delle parole o utilizzare parole dialettali (ricordo il mio primo incontro col "rusco" in *Bar Sport*, che suscitò in me parecchia perplessità, data anche l'assenza della parola nei dizionari d'italiano). Quest'uso di "raspa" mi sembra ricadere in quest'abitudine di Benni.

Answer (score 0):

Il termine ***raspa*** in questo caso descrive un’escrescenza cutanea simile ad una [verruca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/verruca/) che causa prurito nelle parti intime e ti fa grattare. 
Infatti viene richiamato insieme all’[eczema](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eczema/) che è una malattia cutanea.

In questo [dizionario di gergo bolognese](http://www.giovannigiorgi.it/bologna-gergo.php) ho trovato una definizione per raspa che si riferisce ad un "certo prurito" delle parti intime...

Sicuramente nel testo il significato è quello di irritazione delle parti intime.

Comment: Hai una fonte per questa accezione di “raspa”?

Comment: Dalle mie parti (Liguria) ma più che altro nella zona ai confini col basso Piemonte, nel linguaggio colloquiale esiste “avere una raspa” che significa avere molto prurito in una parte del corpo. Inoltre il termine raspa ha anche un’accezione più volgare cioè massaggiarsi le parti intime...

Comment: Quindi la tua fonte è la tua esperienza personale?

Comment: Sì, quindi non so quanto omologabile agli scopi...

Comment: Aggiunto riferimento a dizionario di bolognese

Comment: Anch'io avevo sempre e solo sentito il termine associato all'atto masturbatorio maschile...

Comment: @abarisone: Non vedo questa accezione nel dizionario di gergo bolognese del tuo link.

Comment: Non è un “prurito” delle parti intime, è un atto di masturbazione maschile. Ritengo che derivi dal movimento in avanti e indietro analogo all'uso dell'omonimo utensile per la lavorazione di finitura del legno, così come per “sega”.

Comment: Più comunemente detta: raspone,:)

Comment: Dato il contesto del brano, ritengo che significhi proprio "prurito" e non l'altra accezione (che pure esiste ed è usata) segnalata da DaG

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Io non ho segnalato niente: quello è il significato riportato nel dizionario citato da abarisone, e io avevo da ridire sulla pudica parafrasi.

Comment: @DaG ho utilizzato "segnalata" intendendo "riportata"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Era già stata riportata: sta nella risposta di abarisone. Ho segnalato solo l'eufemismo. :)

Answer (score 0):

La **cheratosi pilare** è una alterazione della cheratinizzazione caratterizzata dalla formazione di tappi cheratinici che vanno ad occludere gli orifizi dei follicoli piliferi.

Hanno un aspetto papulare e puntiforme e sono diffuse soprattutto a livello delle superfici laterali degli arti superiori delle cosce e dei glutei: la palpazione di tali zone produce una *caratteristica sensazione di **raspa***.

Direi che qui **raspa** è una metonimia per *cheratosi pilare*.

Comment: Qual è la fonte di questa spiegazione? E qual è il senso di "raspa" qui?

Comment: Vedi ad esempio [cheratosi pilare](http://www.spazioprevenzione.it/prevenzione/dizionario-medico/). Qui stà ad indicare l'effetto prodotto sulla pelle, resa simile ad una [raspa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspa),  Vedi anche [treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/cheratosi_%28Dizionario-di-Medicina%29/)